# Is there a way to use jqlite by itself

Tags: angularjs

I just want to be able to use the functionality of jqlite and not the full framework of AngularJs.   Is this possible?  If so, how can I set this up without also referencing AngularJs.

Thanks

Comment: Looking for this perhaps? https://code.google.com/p/jqlite/

Comment: are you looking for [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/)?

Comment: @miqid that is not the same thing... angular's got it's own subset of jq functions, but i dont know how standalone it is: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js